# Use checkbox with label to toggle dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-selectors

I'm trying to use a checkbox input with a label to toggle the visibility (`display`) of a dropdown navigation menu. When the menu is shown, I need to move the label to the right in order to be able to still click it since it would otherwise be behind the menu, making it impossible to close.

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <label for="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown-toggle-label"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown-toggle">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, with the way I have set it up, I'm trying to use the `+` selector to

1. show the `.dropdown` menu when the checkbox is checked
2. move the `label` out of the way to have it clickable

This is not possible of course, since not both can directly follow the `input`.

```css
.topnav .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  z-index: 10;
  width: 33%;
}

#dropdown-toggle-label {
  display: block;
}

#dropdown-toggle-label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* move the checkbox out of the way of the menu */
/* this should be done with the label instead */
#dropdown-toggle:checked {
  margin-left: 36%;
}

/* display the menu when the checkbox is checked */
#dropdown-toggle:checked + .dropdown{
  display: block;
}
```

If at all possible, I'd like to solve this issue without using JavaScript.
Should there be any important info missing let me know and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible without Javascript but, you will need to do some re-arrangements on the label and input though. This is what I did

```
<div class="topnav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown-toggle">
    <label for="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown-toggle-label"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Then change the CSS codes after cursor:pointer to

```
#dropdown-toggle:checked, #dropdown-toggle:checked + label{
  transform: translateX(300px); /*Any value you want*/
}

#dropdown-toggle:checked ~ .dropdown{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That worked a charm! Thanks a lot! Another question: Is there a way to have the translation be dependent on the width of the `.dropdown` menu if it has a `max-width`?

Comment: You will need to use "calc()". For example transform: translateX(calc(var(--yourMaxWidth) + 300px));

Comment: The problem is that I have a max-width of 50% on my `.dropdown` menu which does not work with the translation of the label as that would use 50% of the label's width instead of the screen width. Currently, when using a mobile phone, the menu becomes more narrow and the label is shown too far on the right and even clips into another button placed there

Comment: Would you have an image of the current effect and a drawing of the desired effect? A bit hard for me visualise what you are trying to achieve. Because from the codes I didn't see any other buttons.

Comment: Sure. I'll open another issue and link it here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67228886/translating-label-based-on-div-width