# Translating label based on div width

Tags: html, css, label

This is mostly a post to not clutter another one with irrelevant information.

I am trying to use a translation on a label, the distance of which should be based on a menu div next to it. Said menu is initially not displayed and the label acts as a checkbox to show/hide the menu. It also has a set `max-width` based on the page width which is where I'm running into some issues. When the page is wide enough, the translation by the set pixel amount works fine. However, when the page gets too narrow (e.g. on a mobile device), the label is too far to the right and sometimes even clips into the button on the right.
Below are some images to illustrate this.

Menu label with the menu hidden:

[image: Menu label with the menu hidden]

This is the way it currently looks:

[image: This is the way it currently looks]

Here, the label is too far on the right because the menu div is now at its `max-width`.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
.topnav .dropdown {
    display: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;

    z-index: 10;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 50%;

    /* [...] */
}

#dropdown-toggle-label {
    display: block;

    margin: auto 0;
    padding: .5em;
}

#dropdown-toggle:checked + label {
    transform: translateX(215px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(215px);
}

#dropdown-toggle:checked ~ .dropdown{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown-toggle">
    <label for="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown-toggle-label"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        ...
      </ul>
</div>
```

If possible, I'd like to solve this issue without the use of javascript.

EDIT: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z70nrctb/) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Could you create [a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net)? And try to set `width` in `vd` like this `width: 1vw`

Comment: @StepUp So you mean set the `max-width` to `50vw` instead of `50%`? I also added a jsfiddle in the post

Comment: It looks good for me. Could you create an image and show what's wrong?

Comment: There are screenshots in the post above. It happens when the width of the viewport becomes smaller than `400px` because then the `max-width` of the menu will start to come in and the label will be translated too far to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `width` without `max-width` and use `margin-left` to set left gap.

So edited classes would look like this:

```
.topnav .dropdown {
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 215px;
  height: auto;
}

#dropdown-toggle:checked + label {
  margin-left: 230px;
}
```

And if you want to adjust gaps for mobile devices, then we create the following rules:

```
@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .topnav .dropdown {
    width: 24%;
  }

  #dropdown-toggle:checked + label {
    margin-left: 27%;
  }
}
```

An example:

```css
.topnav .dropdown {
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;

  z-index: 10;
  width: 215px;
  height: auto;
}

#dropdown-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#dropdown-toggle-label {
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#dropdown-toggle-label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dropdown-toggle:checked + label {
  margin-left: 230px;
}

#dropdown-toggle:checked ~ .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.topnav .right-bound {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
   .topnav .dropdown {
        width: 24%;
    }

    #dropdown-toggle:checked + label {
        margin-left: 27%;
    }
}


/* Typography (irrelevant for the problem) */

:root {
  --primary-text-color: #fff;
  --highlight-text-color: rgb(10, 138, 101);

  --primary-color: rgb(13, 189, 139);
  --secondary-color: #e9e9e9;
  --background-color: #f6f6f6;

  --primary-highlight-color: rgb(9, 153, 112);
  --secondary-highlight-color: #9c9c9c;

  --topnav-height: 70px;
  --banner-height: 450px;
}

.topnav {
  --clr-highlight: var(--secondary-color);

  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--topnav-height);
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  overflow: hidden;

  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.topnav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--primary-text-color);
}

.topnav .dropdown {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 0 1em 1em 0;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

#dropdown-toggle-label {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: var(--primary-text-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown-toggle">
    <label for="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown-toggle-label">O<i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>
        <a href="/#A">A</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/B">B</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/C">C</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/D">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-bound">
      <li>
        <a href="/login">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You know, I already am using quite a few media queries for the CSS. I'm surprised I hadn't thought about just adding another one.

Comment: @Lithimlin it is ok, sometimes it can be forgotten :)